# Add descriptions / comments to graphql arguments?

Tags: ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

Is it possible to add a description or a comment to the arguments that are accepted in a query with graphql?

I have a Query as follows:

```
    field :users, types[Types::UserType] do
  description 'List of Users. Date parameters accepted in yyyy/mm/dd format.'

  # Required for date range search, accepts string (yyyy/mm/dd)
  argument :from_date, types.String, default_value: nil
```

as you can see, currently I'm adding the description of the parameters to the description of the field.  In the graphiql schema where it describes the types I see:

```
users(from_date: Stringto_date: Stringemail: Stringname: Stringoffset: Intlimit: Int): [UserType]
```

when I click on the from_date it describes a string.  Is there anyway to have it describe the format of the string? eg. "A string in yyyy/mm/dd format."

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Looking at the docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/graphql/1.7.12/GraphQL/Argument), you should be able to do something like:

```
argument :favoriteFood, types.String, "A string in yyyy/mm/dd format", default_value: nil
```